# Does the olympus-om1 tag need updating?

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

The existing [olympus-om1](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympus-om1) tag has a label of

[image]

This week, Olympus launched the mirrorless OM1, as the last in the line using the Olympus name. It's supposed to be under the OM System name, but the camera carries the Olympus label on its body. https://shop.olympus.eu/en_GB/new/om-1

Should the label on the tag be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Uuurgh :-)

I don't think we want one tag to apply to both a film and digital camera, and we can't just simply update the tag description, because then it won't apply to questions like [this one](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97073/am-i-wrong-to-judge-my-exposure-using-my-smartphone) which are about the film camera.

What we probably need to do is:

- Decide which of the film camera and the digital camera we want to have the [olympus-om1](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympus-om1) label.
- Come up with a tag for the other one (maybe [olympus-om1-film](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympus-om1-film) or [olympus-om1-mirrorless](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympus-om1-mirrorless))
- If necessary, rename the current [olympus-om1](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympus-om1) to [olympus-om1-film](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympus-om1-film).

There's also a practical issue here that the Stack Exchange software doesn't let an orphaned tag exist - we'd need an actual question about the digital OM1 to keep it alive.

---

The above is I think uncontroversial. *As a personal view and one that should definitely not be taken to represent the Photography SE moderators*, I'm unconvinced of the value of model-specific tags in general; there's very little in photography which actually applies to only one model of camera. Looking at the 5 questions currently tagged [olympus-om1](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/olympus-om1), only one of them is really about the OM1, the rest are about film photography in general. Personally I would favour just dumping the model-specific tags which removes this problem entirely.

Comment: I'd be on board with dumping the tag entirely. `olympus-omd` covers the E-M1, E-M5 & E-10 series of cameras. Perhaps we then need a new `OM Systems` tag for the next generation, once the branding switches over. It would also be nice to see an `olympus-pen` tag for the PEN range.

Comment: "I'm unconvinced of the value of model-specific tags in general; there's very little in photography which actually applies to only one model of camera." I know you've said that's your opinion, but as a result of this question https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7216/no-nikon-d850-tag a model-specific tag HAS been created. is that simply because that was the first question related to that model of Nikon camera? I think you're suggesting dumping that tag too.

Comment: @spikey_richie I'd argue that tag is (at best) not really adding any value. The one question it's used on pretty much applies to all modern-ish Nikon DSLRs (and maybe mirrorless ones as well). Other people may disagree with me on this one though, hence the "personal view" disclaimer :)

Comment: If a tag isn't useful for organizational purposes, IMO there's no problem with eliminating it (by making it a tag synonym, or editing the few questions it has to something else).

Comment: Regarding the comparison/analogy with the [tag:nikon-d850] tag, I don't know if the comparison fits. I don't think PSE should be all-or-none on camera models. Conceivably, some camera modes could be touchstones or landmarks, and themselves tend to attract lots of questions. To your point, I don't know if the D850 is one of those models (but I'm more aware of Nikon models than other makes, so I may be biased).

Answer (score 1):

My opinion:

Change the old tag to olympus-om1-film. It's been around for a while and there are other things here that have been around for a while that are allowed to remain even though we probably wouldn't treat them the same way if they were added now. This proactively avoids confusing it with the new digital model.

Don't create a new tag for the new digital model just because there's a tag for the film model with the same name. Rather, if someone wants to create such a tag for the newer digital OM-1, we should approach that one as we would any other new tag.

Comment: As per the other comments. Perhaps we just use OMD for all Olympus digital, although we might need to change the tag to `OM Systems` (or add that as a new tag)

Comment: @spikey_richie But there still would be confusion if we leave the [olympus-om1] tag ambiguous as to whether it is referencing the film OM-1 from decades ago or the new digital OM-1.